# Multi-tenency with Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, multi-tenant

We are building a multi-tenant application using spring boot, JPA (Eclipselink). We have done below steps.

1. Defined AbstractRoutingDatasource
2. Defined new Bean of LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean for each tenant

Now in our code, we have two types of flavour.

1. @Persistencecontext

Both do not have a qualifier. Problem is we can not add qualifier example persistence unit name as my tenants will be dynamic.

Is there any way we can solve it. Means on runtime, it will attach the right entity manager with out hardcoding unitname in  the persitenceContext

Thanks a lot